# Updating LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: 16.04, libraries

I have a library at `/home/karnivaurus/libraries/testlib.so` which I want to link to when running an executable. So, in my `.bashrc` file, I added the following line:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/karnivaurus/libraries`

However, when I run `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the command line, it prints out:

`:/home/karnivaurus/libraries`

My two questions are:

1) Why has `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` had its default paths deleted (e.g. `/lib`, `/usr/lib` etc.)

2) How can I restore `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to its default paths?

Thanks!

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is unset by default - the default library search paths are built in to the dynamic loader

Comment: Better use `-L` option when compiling with *gcc* and `-rpath` when linking with `ld`.